# GAE gunicorn flask best way to act with requests that takes 30-60 minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, beautifulsoup, youtube-data-api, gunicorn

I built an application with flask that shall be able to crawl some data. First step is to use the Youtube Data API to get some data about a user, including a list of all videos the user ever uploaded. That totally works fine! After I got the list of Video Ids I try to scrape all these videos on youtube to extract the likes and views over all videos and sum them together to 2 big numbers. I tested it local without gunicorn and not in the app engine, it works fine! But when a user uploaded 6700 videos it may take 30 min to complete the request (local it works).
[image]
When I try to run the same code in the GAE it returns 502 Bad Gateway after several minutes, but in the logs I see it is still crawling.
This is the GET 502:
[image: 502 Bad Gateway Request]

Worker continued scraping for several minutes.
[image: End of Logs]

Here is the Code I wrote to crawl:
This is my app.yaml. With -t 36000 Workers can be silent for one hour until they are killed and restarted.

```
runtime: python37
service: crawler
entrypoint: . ./env.inc.sh && gunicorn -t 36000 -b :$PORT app:app
```

This is the route in my app.py which is called:

```py
@app.route('/youtube/username/<user>')
def youtubeStatistics(user):
    response = crawler.crawl_youtube_user(os.environ['YOUTUBE_API_KEY'], user)
    if response:
        return jsonify(response), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"prettyMessage": "Quota Limit maybe Exceeded"}), 403
```

These are my crawler functions I use:

```py
def scrape_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    page = r.text
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def crawl_youtube_user(KEY, username):
    youtube = set_up(KEY)
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        forUsername=username
    )
    uploadPlaylistId = ""
    data = {}
    try:
        response = request.execute()
    except:
        return {}
    if (response["pageInfo"]["totalResults"] > 0):
        stats = response["items"][0]["statistics"]
        data["subscriberCount"] = stats["subscriberCount"]
        data["videoCount"] = stats["videoCount"]
        data["publishedAt"] = response["items"][0]["snippet"]["publishedAt"]
        uploadPlaylistId = response["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]
        request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails",
            maxResults=50,
            playlistId=uploadPlaylistId
        )
        videoIds = []
        while True:
            try:
                response = request.execute()
            except:
                return {}
            for vid in response["items"]:
                videoIds.append(vid["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"])
            if "nextPageToken" not in response:
                break
            else:
                request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
                    part="snippet,contentDetails",
                    maxResults=50,
                    playlistId=uploadPlaylistId,
                    pageToken=response["nextPageToken"]
                )
        data.update(crawl_youtube_videos(videoIds))
    return data


def crawl_youtube_videos(ids):
    data = {'viewCount': 0, 'videoLikes': 0}
    counter = 0
    idlength = len(ids)
    for id in ids:
        counter += 1
        print('{}/{}: Scraping Youtube videoId {}'.format(counter,idlength,id))
        soup = scrape_url('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}&gl=DE&hl=de'.format(id))
        try:
            data['viewCount'] += int(soup.find('div', class_='watch-view-count').getText().split(' ')[0].replace('.', '').replace(',', ''))
        except:
            print("Error while trying to extract the views of a Video: {}.".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
        try:
            data['videoLikes'] += int(soup.find("button",{"title": "Mag ich"}).find("span").getText().replace('.', '').replace(',', ''))
        except:
            print("Error while trying to extract the likes of a Video: {}.".format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
    return data
```

I dont want to use more threads or something like this, to make the whole process faster! Im scared about my IP getting blocked or something like this, if I scrape to many sites in a short time. I just try to keep the request alive until I get the response I want. 
So are there more mechanisms which protects the GAE-App from long response time or something like this? **And what would be the best way to act with requests which take 30-60 minutes?**

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a background task queue like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/).

When in place, your request would queue a job. You can then query the task queue and get the job status as you wish.

[Here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) is a great resource for getting started with either of these options.